# Error: /dev/hugepages does not exist

Tags: mount

Today, when I run a command for DPDK (Data plane developement kit) on ubuntu:

sudo mount -t hugetlbfs -o pagesize=1G none /dev/hugepages

I got error like this:

mount: mount point /dev/hugepages does not exist

Anyone can tell me how I can fix this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to mount any other local directory?

for example,
mkdir /mnt/huge
try to point the mount point to /mnt/huge

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  In this Q&A format, answers are reserved for definitive solutions to the question.  Clarifying questions, diagnostic suggestions, and speculative solutions should be done in a comment, which requires a little more rep.  If a comment turns out to be the solution, it can be expanded and re-posted as an answer.

Comment: edited the answer to remove action item and questions

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `1GB` huge pages for DPDK please follow the steps as

1. edit the `/etc/default/grub` as grub `default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=1` (for 1GB 1 Huge page)
2. update the grub settings via `update-grub` tool.
3. to mount the huge page to desired `mkdir /dev/huge1G; mount -t hugetlbfs -o pagesize=1G none /dev/huge1G`
4. Start DPDK application with rte_eal_init args as `--huge-dir=/dev/huge1G`

Note: these can be performed on a Linux Kernel which has enabled Huge pages. To check if huge pages are build execute `grep -nr HUGE /boot/config*`

```
CONFIG_HUGETLBFS=y
CONFIG_HUGETLB_PAGE=y
```